# Change Time Zone in Wave Dashboard

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, saql

I am using page 28 of this doc for reference: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_dev_guide_saql.pdf

I need to change the time zone in the step. I am trying to use the computeExpression action to handle it. Here is the code I tried:

```
 "CreatedDate_Hour_3": {
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "id": "0Fb32000000TVRzCAO",
                    "label": "Case_Article_Survey",
                    "name": "Case_Article_Survey",
                    "url": "/services/data/v38.0/wave/datasets/0Fb32000000TVRzCAO"
                }
            ],
            "isFacet": true,
            "isGlobal": false,
            "query": {
                "pigql": "q = load \"Case_Article_Survey\";\r\nq = group q by 'CreatedDate_Hour';\r\nq = foreach q generate 'CreatedDate_Hour' as 'CreatedDate_Hour', count() as 'count';\r\nq = order q by 'CreatedDate_Hour' asc;\r\nq = limit q 2000;",
                "measures": [
                    [
                        "count",
                        "*",
                        "count"
                    ]
                ],
                "action": "computeExpression",
                "parameters": {
                    "source": "CreatedDate_Hour",
                    "mergeWithSource": true,
                    "computedFields": [
                        {
                            "name": "CreatedDate_Hour_adjusted",
                            "type": "Datetime",
                            "format": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                            "saqlExpression": "toDate(CreatedDate_Hour  - 8*3600)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "measuresMap": {},
                "autoFilter": true,
                "groups": [
                    "CreatedDate_Hour"
                ]
            },
            "selectMode": "single",
            "type": "aggregateflex",
            "useGlobal": false,
            "visualizationParameters": {
                "options": {}
            }
        },
```

This code is not subtracting 8 hours from CreatedDate_Hour.

Answer (score 0):

`CreatedDate` is actually a `DateTime` field and you've specified a format of `MM/dd/yyyy` to which you want to add `hours`. You've omitted the `HH:mm:ss` needed by a DateTime, particularly since you're going to add or subtract hours to adjust the time zone. Take a look at the `toDate` functions on page 26 of the document you referenced for more insight on this.

The `toDate(CreatedDate_Hour_3 - 8*3600)` subtracts 8 hours from `CreatedDate_Hour_3`. Is that what you want to do? Will all of that data from your SAQL query be in a time zone that's 8 hours different than you want? If not, you'll need to adjust your code even further.

**Edit:**

In the example you referenced, it takes an existing date `CreatedDate_sec_epoch` and subtracts 8 hours to create a new date `CreateDateNew`. The equivalent in your code would require that your dataset have a field named `CreatedDate_Hour_3`. The error message that you're now receiving would indicate that either the field doesn't exist, or else isn't properly formatted.

I recommend you look at your source data to determine exactly what format it's in and then adjust your code accordingly. That would seem to be what the original error message was likely telling you to begin with, but not with enough specificity to recognize it.

Comment: Yes all of the Created Date data needs to have 8 hours subtracted.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but now I am seeing Invalid IDTOKEN: CreatedDate_Hour_3

Comment: See my edit. I think there's an issue with your source data.

Comment: See edit. I updated the code to use the CreatedDate_Hour in the computeExpression. No change reflected in the dashboard.

Comment: I suspect that your source data is labeled `CreatedDate`, which is what you want to replace when your query runs.